# How can I connect my flutter app to my azure database?

Tags: azure, flutter

I made a database in Azure and it is updated every day with more data. But now I want to retrieve some data from the azure database to my flutter app. But do not know how to make a connection between flutter and azure DB.

Thank you!

Comment: What type of database it is? SQL Server, CosmoDB, etc...  In most scenario, you will need a Rest API that can read data from your database and expose data through endpoints.

Comment: Hi, it is a SQL server in Azure and it is hosted on a SQL server. @PatrickTshibanda

Answer (score 2):

Your flutter app cannot connect to the Azure SQL database. You need to create a REST API, which will expose data from your database to your mobile app.

You can create an API with ASP.NET CORE, Node.JS, Python, etc.

Here are some resources that can help you :

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flutter/flutter_accessing_rest_api.htm

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connect-query-nodejs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connect-query-nodejs?tabs=windows)